# Button with Glyphicon is smaller than button with text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the current page (with glyphicons in buttons as download buttons).

[image]

As seen in the picture the final column with the glyphicons don't quite line up. I tried replacing the glyphicons with just a "test" in the button and they seem to line up perfectly.

[image]

This is the line of code that has to do with one of the buttons for that column.

```
document.getElementById('column_4').innerHTML += '<div class="col-md-auto"> <button type="button" id =' + array13[prop] + ' name = "Rec_Status"  onclick="gotovendor(0)" value = ' + array13[prop] + ' class="list-group-item" onclick="myFunction7(this.value)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>';
```

How do I have the buttons with glyphicons in the first image align like the buttons in the second image? I tried using padding, but it doesn't look like a good solution.

Below is the the same code with padding.

```
document.getElementById('column_4').innerHTML += '<div class="col-md-auto"> <button type="button" id =' + array13[prop] + ' name = "Rec_Status" style = "padding: 0.625vw;" onclick="gotovendor(0)" value = ' + array13[prop] + ' class="list-group-item" onclick="myFunction7(this.value)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some padding/font-size/line-height.

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<button style="padding:5%;font-size:20px" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
<button class="btn  btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
```